# Retrieve data with a SELECT and treat it separately

Tags: python, sql-server, select

I need to do a `SELECT` to an SQL Server table and treat the information I get separately.

For example, let's say I have this table named `Table1`

And I do this SELECT in python:

```
SELECT name, phone, date FROM Table1
```

In the print the result would be:

> [['Sara Miller',611111111],['Jane Smith',622222222],['Amanda
>   Laurens',633333333]]

I need to treat each row and each name and phone number separately to send SMS... So, how can I access each one using Python?
For example, to send an SMS to the number 611111111 saying

> "Dear Sara Miller, tomorrow (20/05/2020) you have an appointment in
>   the Clinic"

The SMS part I have covered, using an API, the problem is I can't figure out how to treat received data from SQL Server.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("Connection parameters, waorking OK")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name, phone, date FROM Table1')
result = cursor.fetchall()
final_result = [list(i) for i in result]
print(final_result)
```

If I need to clarify something please let me know.

Comment: Add the python code you tried to your question. You can use a cursor in the python script in a loop to read each row individually.

Comment: I added some code. I though on doing a foreach x in final_result, but don't know how to "access" each data separately (name, phone, etc separately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really worked with `pypyodbc` so I'm not sure what the format of the data that `cursor.fetchall` returns so I have listed two approaches which should cover both scenarios.

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("Connection parameters, waorking OK")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name, phone, date FROM Table1')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    name = row[0]
    phone = row[1]
    date = row[2]
    # do something with these variables
```

If the result returned is a *dict* instead of a *list* then it becomes:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    name = row['name']
    phone = row['phone']
    date = row['date']
    # do something with these variables
```

Or as @DanGuzman mentions we can also do:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    name = row.name
    phone = row.phone
    date = row.date
    # do something with these variables
```

Comment: With pyodbc, one can specify `row.name` instead of `row['name']`.

Comment: added that approach as well

Comment: Trying your first approach and I get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str ... So now I'm trying to figure out how to concatenate correctly when printing!

Comment: Ok, I got it! using format() --> print("{}{}".format(a, b)) it works and know I can manipulate data with your first approach. Can't upvote you because I'm new, but marked as the good answer :)